# Syncfusion PdfDocument and CultureInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, syncfusion

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC app.

I'm working with Syncfusion's PdfDocument (ver 7.303.0.20) in order to generate PDF files.

My app's CultureInfo is set based on my user's preference.

The problem I have is that when I instantiate a new PdfDocument the CurrentCulture changes to Invariant. I have a feeling this is a bug in PdfDocument, but maybe I'm wrong and there's a way to properly instantiate this object?

Did anyone encounter that before? My searches came up with nothing..

I know I can store the current culture before instantiating the PDF object and then to re-set the current culture, but this doesn't feel right..

I've already touched base with Syncfusion's support team, but meanwhile I thought I'd drop it the question here too.

Let's see who's faster!  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for not updating - I upgraded to version 8 and all good now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with the latest versions? it is fixed.

Thanks